# QML: Injecting Item into hierarchy of Items

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have a reusable item which looks like this:

Reusable.qml:

```
Flickable {
    CustomCppComponent {
        id: customComponent
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to instantiate it with some extra child:

Main.qml:

```
Item {
    Reusable {
        Rectangle {
            id: rect
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
}
```

But I want `Rectangle` to be placed as a child of `CustomComponent` so the equivalent would be:

Main.qml:

```
Item {
    Flickable {
        CustomCppComponent {
            id: customComponent
            Rectangle {
                id: rect
                anchors.fill: parent
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a `default property`.

Reusable.qml:

```
Flickable {
    default property alias innerContents: customComponent.data
    CustomCppComponent {
        id: customComponent
    }
}
```

Since `innerContents` is the default property, any child objects that you add to your `Reusable` instance will get added to `innerContents`, which is pointing at customComponent's `data` property.

This assumes that `CustomCppComponent` is a visual item of course, which your question did not define.